# is there a better way to hold this data then a dictionary of dictionaries of dictionaries? python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am creating a data structure dynamically that holds car information. The dictionary looks something like this:

```
cars = {'toyota': {'prius': {'transmission':'automatic', 'mpg':30, 'misc':[]}}}
```

The outermost dictionary contains car brand (toyota, bmw, etc.), the second dictionary contains model (prius, m5, etc.) and the inner dictionary contains details of the car. Is this the best way to hold this information?

I am both building the data structure and accessing it. I can't really think of another way to do it but the code looks kind of messy with a bunch of:

```
cars['toyota'].setdefault('prius', {}).setdefault('misc', []).append('hello')
```

Comment: I would agree that it looks kind of messy but I just wrote an algorithm involving recursive tuples of dicts of tuples of dicts and lists `({'dir': ({'dir': ({}, ['file', 'file']), 'dir': ({}, ['file'])}, ['file', 'file', 'file'])}, ['file', 'file'])`

Comment: @Carson - that's a nasty structure... any reason it's not being re-factored?

Comment: @Wayne I could have used classes instead of tuples, but I wanted the dirs separate from the files, and I opted for tuples instead rather than instantiating a whole bunch of objects. And actually the algorithm is pretty nice, not as complex as the structure

Comment: @Carson, technically speaking, creating tuples *is* instantiating a bunch of objects - they're just a very specific type of objects. As for the separation, just having some "dir" objects and some "file" objects (renamed to avoid collisions/shadowing, of course), would probably produce the same effect as your complex data structure, but with a little more readability. Not sure about the speed of creating a ton of custom objects v. tuples/dicts, but I'd guess it's nearly the same.

Comment: @Wayne that's true -- in any case, I chose this encoding to suit my algorithm. The data structure is dynamically generated whereas the algorithm is not. In any case, I found it easy to sort the dirs, recurse into them, and upon completion of processing the first tuple element of a given dir, sort and iterate over the second tuple element. This structure is also similar to how the output is structured, so it made everything flow nicely.

Answer (score 12):

As Justin suggested, classes would be ideal.

You could easily do something like this:

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, make, model=None, trans=None, mpg=None, misc=None):
        if make == 'Toyta' and model is None:
            model = 'Prius'
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.transmission = trans
        self.mpg = mpg
        if misc is None:
            self.misc = []
    #other class stuff here
    def __str__(self):
        return "Make: {make} Model: {model} Mpg: {mpg}".format(make=self.make,
                                                               model=self.model,
                                                               mpg=self.mpg)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

cars = [Car('Toyota', 'Prius', 'Automatic', '30'), 
        Car('Mitsubishi', 'Echo LRX', 'Automatic', '20')]

for car in cars:
    print car
```

HTH!

Comment: Nice! I wanted to up vote this but one day after I had reached the limit to upvote, they are still asking me to come back after 3 effing hours. There is some glitch.

Comment: And the nice thing about Python (and similar languages) is that Lance's request of having the data structure be dynamic still works with classes, since you can dynamically add and remove attributes.

Answer (score 5):

Python has [classes](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html).  I don't know if it makes sense with your data structure, but you could organize everything into a collection of `Car` classes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create  JSON structure? Semantically you might be able to gain a little more expressiveness rather than accessing your data as dictionary elements.

Comment: I believe JSON would still not be what Lance actually wants.

Answer (score 0):

One idea - flatten the nested dictionary keyed by a multi-segment name separated by period. E.g.

```
cars.setvalue('toyota.prius.transmission', 'automatic')
cars.setvalue('toyota.prius.mpg', '30')
cars.setvalue('toyota.prius.misc', [])

cars.getvalue('toyota.prius.misc').append('hello')

class Car:
    def setvalue(self, key, value):
        # parse the key and do your mess here, like
        # cars['toyota'].setdefault('prius', {}).setdefault('misc', [])
```